# PayPal REST live issues

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using PayPal REST api using Python's `paypalrestsdk`.I have got 3 problems with my PayPal sell page:

1. the price of the item is not shown beside the cart icon. I've got only the icon with no text beside it.
2. the url is `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=XXXXXXXXX` NOT like I've seen in many modern webapps `https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=XXXXXXX`, what is the diffrence between the 2 urls?
3. I have no `Pay with Debit or Credit Card` button. This is only working in `sandbox` not in `live`

My payment object is as follows:

```
payment = Payment({
            "intent": "sale",
            "payer": {
                "payment_method": "paypal"
            },
            "redirect_urls": {
                "return_url": settings.HOME_URL + reverse('usr-pay-process'),
                "cancel_url": settings.HOME_URL + reverse('usr-pay-cancel')
            },
            "transactions": [{
                "amount": {
                "total": "1.00",
                "currency": "USD"
            },
            "description": "My Item"
            }]
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the below answers for your questions.

Q1. I see that item details are not passed on your CreatePayment API request, Pass the item details in the transaction object. Refer the following link for more information about Payments API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/

Q2. No answer. Check with PayPal support.

Q3. Check your PayPal live account email is confirmed, are you using personal or Business account. Also check if guest checkout/ account optional settings is enabled on your PayPal website preference. otherwise please contact PayPal support in the following URL: https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask